# preg_split url slug and id

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I currently have this URL pattern:

```
foo-bar-1
bar-foo-bar-2
etc
```

I'd like to get the words separated from the number but I'm having some trouble completely understanding how to do that.

I started with this which got me close:

```
$slug = 'foo-bar-1';
preg_split('/(\d+)$/', $slug);

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'foo-bar-' (length=8)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
```

But I can't seem to finish it up.  I'd like it to be this:

```
array (size=2)
      0 => string 'foo-bar' (length=7)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Instead of splitting, use `preg_match()` to extract both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_split('/-(?=\d+$)/', $slug);
```

I use `-` as separator and I check if it is followed by a number at the end of the string with a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=...)`